# Filtering a objects in objects for ReactJS

Tags: javascript, regex, reactjs, filter, redux

I tried to filter objects value. But, I don't know how to approach an object in an object value to filter. For example, I want to find specific data which includes the user's name value called James who is the winner. I tried to use "match.win.user.name.match(regex)". It doesn't work. please help me. Thank you.

```
    case FILTER_MATCH:
      return {
        ...state,
        filtered: state.matches.filter(match => {
          const regex = new RegExp(`${action.payload}`, 'gi');
          return (
            match.date.match(regex) ||
            match.game.match(regex) ||
            match.win.user.name.match(regex) <-- error!
          );
        })
      };



    object match: {
    matches: [
      {
        _id: '5d4d0796b60bd206cc8e72d8',
        win: [
          {
            _id: '5d4d0796b60bd206cc8e72d9',
            user: {
              _id: '5d4942777a26a8df93097ef5',
              name: 'james',
              email: 'james@gmail.com'
            }
          }
        ],
        lose: [
          {
            _id: '5d4d0796b60bd206cc8e72da',
            user: {
              _id: '5d4942ea7a26a8df93097ef6',
              name: 'rob',
              email: 'rob@gmail.com'
            }
          }
        ],
        draw: [],
        game: 'Tic-Tac-Toe',
        date: '2019-08-09T05:41:42.494Z',
        __v: 0
      },


Error message

Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
(anonymous function)
src/reducers/match.js:42
  39 | ...state,
  40 | filtered: state.matches.filter(match => {
  41 |   const regex = new RegExp(`${action.payload}`, 'gi');
> 42 |   return (
     | ^  43 |     match.date.match(regex) ||
  44 |     match.game.match(regex) ||
  45 |     match.win.user.name.match(regex)
```

Comment: before accessing nested properties you need to check the existence of property, i.e. `match && match.win && match.win.user && match.win.user.name && match.win.user.name.match(regex)`

Comment: Thanks for answering. But, It still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are accessing the user incorrectly. By calling match.win.user you try to access the object user from win, but as seen in your data object win is an array with one user object. If you remove the [] brackets around user, it should work.

```
 win: [
      {
        _id: '5d4d0796b60bd206cc8e72d9',
        user: {
          _id: '5d4942777a26a8df93097ef5',
          name: 'james',
          email: 'james@gmail.com'
        }
      }
    ]
```

to

```
 win: {
        _id: '5d4d0796b60bd206cc8e72d9',
        user: {
          _id: '5d4942777a26a8df93097ef5',
          name: 'james',
          email: 'james@gmail.com'
        }
      }
```

If you need to have win as an array (you should call them wins then), you can access the user like this:

```
match.win.length !== 0 && match.win[0].user.name.match(regex)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: It's a perfect solution. Thanks a lot!